# How to send email with Nodemailer to prevent email merging

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

currently using nodemailer and gmail as a way to send an email notification of new activities that is going on in our website. Question is, the email sent is always merged together due to same subject.

Is it possible to add a filter to prevent email services such as Gmail to auto merge the email? Preferably if I do not have to change the subject of the email.

Answer (score 0):

"Conversation View" is a feature of Gmail. Unfortunately there is no option to stop the merging of emails in Gmail (either by the sender or receiver).